# Does PyGobject have any reference books?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm trying to learn pygobject but could find any books. The reference manual in https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Window.html#Gtk.Window has syntax but no examples. is there a way to get started?

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is for sure:

The Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial
https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Also look at the code of the demo that comes with pygobject
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/-/tree/master/examples/demo

Comment: Yes, the tutorial is good, it's brief however.

Answer (score 1):

"Foundations of PyGTK Development (2nd edition)" is the book that I'm currently reading, it's also **the only** book that I could find on GTK+ development with Python. The reasons are probably that GTK+ is mostly Linux focused (although it's cross platform) and python isn't widely used for desktop development. Anyway, I'm reading this book and liking it so far.